# What is the complexity of these Dictionary methods?

Tags: c#, complexity-theory, time-complexity

Can anyone explain what is the complexity of the following `Dictionary` methods?

```
ContainsKey(key)
Add(key,value);
```

I'm trying to figure out the complexity of a method I wrote:

```
public void DistinctWords(String s)
{
    Dictionary<string,string> d = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    String[] splitted = s.split(" ");
    foreach ( String ss in splitted)
    { 
        if (!d.containskey(ss))
            d.add(ss,null);
    } 
}
```

I assumed that the 2 dictionary methods are of log(n) complexity where *n* is the number of keys in the dictionary. Is this correct?

Comment: No, I believe both ``ContainsKey`` and ``Add`` are constant-time in the average case.  *Edit*: Also you should check out a ``HashSet``.  It does what you're trying to use a ``Dictionary`` for much more cleanly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This routine, as a whole, is, effectively, O(m) time complexity, with m being the number of strings in your search.

This is because [Dictionary.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4.aspx) and [Dictionary.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k.aspx) are both (normally) O(1) operations.

(It's slightly more complicated than that, as Dictionary.Add can be O(n) for n items in the Dictionary, but only when the dictionary capacity is small.  As such, if you construct your dictionary with a large enough capacity up front, it would be O(m) for m string entries.)

That being said, if you're only using the Dictionary for existence checking, you could use a `HashSet<string>`.  This would allow you to write:

```
  public void DistinctWords(String s)
  {
     HashSet<string> hash = new HashSet<string>(s.Split(' '));

     // Use hash here...
```

As your dictionary is a local variable, and not stored (at least in your code), you could also use LINQ:

```
 var distinctWords = s.Split(' ').Distinct();
```

Comment: How come retrieving is O(n) for small capacity dictionaries? documentaions mention that a hash table is behind the scene. hence the complexity should be O(1)

Comment: @ShahryarSaljoughi the reason it is O(M) is because M is the amount of strings in the example from above...
Even though you do O(1) operation, you do it M times

Answer (score 52):

It's written in the documentation for [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)...

> The Dictionary generic class provides a mapping from a set of keys to a set of values. Each addition to the dictionary consists of a value and its associated key. Retrieving a value by using its key is very fast, close to O(1), because the Dictionary class is implemented as a hash table.

And for the [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k.aspx) function:

> If Count is less than the capacity, this method approaches an O(1) operation. If the capacity must be increased to accommodate the new element, this method becomes an O(n) operation, where n is Count.

Answer (score 24):

Both methods have constant complexity:

- ContainsKey(key) - O(1)
- Add(key,value) - O(1)

Comment: What about the `ContainsValue` method?

Comment: ContainsValue  is O(n).

Comment: Are they O(1) or just close? The documentation says that it's close,  but not quite

Answer (score 8):

That is not correct, generally dictionaries / hashtable lookup is O(1). To do this it will generate a hash from the key your are looking for and only compare it to items that have the same hash - with a good hashing algorithm this is considered O(1) overall ([amortized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis) O(1) - only in the rare occasion that the capacity must be increased for an addition you have O(n)).

Comment: "compare it to items that have the same hash". In order to see the same hash items, wouldn't it need to iterate?

Comment: With a good hashing algorithm collisions are very rare and you only have to iterate over the collision list

Answer (score 3):

The ContainsKey and Add method are close to O(1).

ContainsKey documentation:

> This method approaches an O(1) operation.

Add documentation:

> If Count is less than the capacity, this method approaches an O(1)
>   operation. If the capacity must be increased to accommodate the new
>   element, this method becomes an O(n) operation, where n is Count.

If you are using Framework 3.5 or later, you can use a `HashSet<T>` instead of a dictionary with dummy values:

```
public void DistinctWords(String s) {
  HashSet<string> d = new HashSet<string(s.split(" "));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Both are constant time:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k.aspx

One caveat however:

"If Count is less than the capacity, this method approaches an O(1) operation. If the capacity must be increased to accommodate the new element, this method becomes an O(n) operation, where n is Count."