# Most efficient way to sort through "big" datasets which are refreshed every 15 minutes

Tags: c#, mysql, datatable, .net-core

I have roughly 200 Json-Datasets which contain ~ 100.000 rows each.
The "Main" Dataset (Which contains all of the Subsets) is structed: Name, Dataset.
The "Sub"-Datasets are all structured the same way: ID, Name, Value.

Also, I'm very new with "big" datasets and thus never encountered anything even remotly "complex".

The IDs in the Dataset is not unique and I'm only looking for the lowest value of each ID for each Dataset.

So a "Sub"-Dataset might have ~100.000 rows but it can be reduced to ~ 8.000 rows in the style of: ID, Name, LowestValue

An example would be:

```
{(1,"AAA",10),(1,"AAA",4),(1,"AAA",15),(5,"CCC",28),(5,"CCC",20)}
```

Which could be reduced to:

```
{(1,"AAA",4),(5,"CCC",20)}
```

Due to the Datasets changing every ~ 15 minutes I have to "update" my "local" list of lowest values. (This update can have less or more unique Ids so I have to "clear" my local list, if I just update the values I might keep an Id which should've been removed)

**I would like to arrive at a repeatable task (either run in a task with while(true) or being called every 15 minutes) which sorts through the Datasets. This data needs to be accessible with a function where I can check "What is the lowest value of XX in Dataset Nr. 10" (This function is not needed here, my question is purely about getting a nudge in the right direction of how to effectivly sort and store my data in either a local variable or a local sql database(or if there's something better))**

I have two approaches so far, varying in success:

---

**The Slow And Dumb Way(?):**
Essentially what I did is make a BIG list and start looping through each Set and check if a) the value is already in the list and b) if the value is bigger than the one I currently check.

Not only was this insanely slow but I also never actually remove / create a temp list and merge it. I pretty much stopped this approach due to its insanely low speed.

```
List<(int DataSetNumber, long ID, string Name, long Value)> My_Data= new List<(int DataSetNumber, long ID, string Name, long Value)>();

foreach (var Current_Dataset in All_Datasets)
{
    foreach (var CurrentSet in Dataset)
    {
    var TempItem = My_Data.FindIndex(x => x.DataSetNumber == Current_Dataset.Number &&  x.ID== CurrentSet.ID>);
    if (TempItem >= 0)
    {
       if(My_Data[TempItem].Value > CurrentSet.Value)
             My_Data[TempItem] = (CurrentSet.DataSetNumber, CurrentSet.ID, CurrentSet.Name, CurrentSet.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        My_Data.Add((CurrentSet.DataSetNumber, CurrentSet.ID, CurrentSet.Name, CurrentSet.Value));
    }

    }
}
```

---

**The SQL Way**
Since I already have a local database in which I store other data I thought "Why not add stuff to said list". 
I've created 200 tables and looped through the local data and added my "reduced" data to said tables (Aka each Dataset got its own table).

My Connection String:

```
string conn = @"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = DATABASE.mdf; Integrated Security = True";
```

I first created a temp list:

```
List<(long ID, string Name, long Value)> Temp_List = new List<(long ID, string Name, long Value)>();
```

Sorted my Data into it and then uploaded it to the table:

```
                    foreach (var (ID, Name, Value) in Temp_List)
                    {

                        string query = @"INSERT INTO " + "\"" + DataSet.ID + "\" (Id, Name, Value)";
                        query += " Values (@id, @name, @value)";
                        SqlCommand InsertAuction = new SqlCommand(query, sql);
                        InsertAuction.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ID.ToString());
                        InsertAuction.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Name);
                        InsertAuction.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", Value.ToString());
                        InsertAuction.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
```

I've now ran into the problem that:

1. the "REPLACE" command doesnt work / seem to exist in the MS SQL
2. When creating a Temp Table I also cant TRUNCATE my current Table which is supposed to be replaced
3. I still have no clue if this is even the most efficient way.

---

So my question is: What is a recommended way to handle data like this? Should I just scrap both ideas and solve it differently? Is creating a temporary table, dropping the target table and then migrating my temporary table into it the way to go?

Comment: Is the highest value of long ID in a sub dataset around 8000?

Comment: Does your application use a database anyway and profits from data stored there (e.g. several clients that access the data)? I don't know c# so i cannot improve your code myself, but you seem to be using a very slow way to evaluate/store your data (you run FindIndex 200*100k times (O(N))). So unless you use a distributed application, local parsing/storage seems to be the way to go; c# has json parsers to operate directly on your input, and to store your data, try e.g. a [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7532678). Maybe find/ask a specific c# question about how to implement this properly.

Comment: it depends on how you get the dataset (e.g. file IO), how you parse it (e.g. in-memory vs stream), what data you need (e.g. ignore name and just keep id), if you reduce to ~8000 each before combining 200 datasets). From the little information about your overall system, my current recommendation would be a code-based solution. e.g. custom json reader (stream based, ignoring string values) that already reduces the json to a Dictionary<int,int> (or long,long if really needed), then a 2nd part that reduces 200 Dictionaries into one.