# algorithm that is less than O(n2) time complexity

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm trying to modify this algorithm which is of complexity O(n2) to something quicker.
the algorithm is supposed to do the following

```
Input: nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9
Output: [0,1]
Output: Because nums[0] + nums[1] == 9, we return [0, 1].
```

Any help is appreciated.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class Solution
{
    public int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target)
    {
        int[] output = new int[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < nums.Length; n++)
            {
                if ((nums[i] + nums[n]) == target)
                {
                    output[0] = n;
                    output[1] = i;
                }
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe sorting first could help

Comment: Can you help with an example please, thanx

Comment: You can double the speed, by taking the inner loop from `i` rather than `0`...

Comment: You can also be smart, and binary search for the value of `nums[n]` you're after, rather than doing a linear search (since the input is sorted, at least in your example). That brings you down a bit further

Comment: Note that some of the suggestions here may be *algorithmically* quicker, but they're unlikely to be faster with sensible inputs, due to the added complexity and object allocations

Comment: If you want to explain your genius to your teacher select one of the the other answers, but only if you can explain it and reproduce your genius.

Comment: it seams like Vishal solution was the quickest, it took nearly 240 ms, for Dimitry solution it took 416ms , for Strom it took 456 ms, the original solution posted by me too 800 ms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to code an O(n) solution, you should loop the elements(numbers) of the array only one time. So, you need to store them in a dictionary. Keys will be numbers, Values will be their indexes. Then  will check that is there any key whose value is equal to target - number in the dictionary. [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-5.0)<TKey, TValue> is a good choice for this problem.

```
public class Solution {
public int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target)
{
    //Declare key-value dictionary to store numbers
    var set = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    
    //Loop each number in the array until find the complementary number.
    for (var i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
    {
        //Assign the element of the array to a integer variable to have an elegant code.
        var number = nums[i];
        
        //If the dictionary contains the complementary number then return it.
        if (set.ContainsKey(target - number))
        {
            return new[] {set[target - number], i};
        }
        
        //If the current number is not a complementary number then add it to the dictionary.
        if (!set.ContainsKey(number))
        {
            set.Add(number, i);
        }
    }
    //throw the right exception if there is no valid solution.
    throw new ArgumentException();
}
}
```

Comment: I have opted to use Hashtable which is a is a non-generic collection that stores key-value pairs, similar to generic Dictionary<TKey, TValue> collection. You can use either of them, whatever you're more comfortable with since both of them will be doing the same exact thing.

Comment: @Strom you're wrong, it'll only run false for the first time. The value is being added later. Try doing a dry run or running on your computer you'll be able to understand it better then.

Comment: You could save a lot of object allocations by using a `Dictionary<int, int>`, but otherwise this is a significantly neater solution than @Dmitry's IMO. An explanation would be nice however. Using TryGetValue would also speed it up

Comment: @canton7 yes you're right, actually, I focused only on time complexity my bad. No problem I'll update the answer with an explanation.

Comment: Really neat! `var map = new Dictionary<int, int>();` and then `map.TryAdd(nums[i], i);` instead of `map[nums[i]] = i;`

Comment: You could also use the Dictionary ctor which takes an initial capacity to avoid the resizing cost, although that means you might allocate more than necessary in the success case

Comment: @DmitryBychenko thanks, I've actually updated it  :)

Comment: this is the quickest solution it took around 240 ms , thanks alot

Comment: You can still use `TryGetValue` to avoid the double lookup of `ContainsKey` / the indexer. You can also use `TryAdd` instead of `ContainsKey`/`Add`

Comment: Is this considered using dynamic programming memoization? I am saying that because you are saving old calculations in a Dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have good hash function, you can have `O(n)` complexity. For each `p` within `num` you should check if `q = k - p` exists within `num`. You can do each each check with `O(1)` if you use hash based collection (here `Dictionary<int, int[]>`). The only little problem is `p = q = k/2`; here we should check if *two* equal items `k/2` are in `num`.

```
    using System.Linq;

    ...

    public static int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int k) {
      if (nums == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(nums));

      var dict = nums
        .Select((value, index) => new { value = (long)value, index })
        .GroupBy(pair => pair.value, pair => pair.index)
        .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.ToArray());

      for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; ++i) {
        long p = nums[i];
        long q = k - p;

        if (dict.TryGetValue(q, out var array))
          if (p != q)
            return new int[] { i, array[0] };
          else if (array.Length >= 2)
            return new int[] { array[0], array[1] };
      }

      return new int[] { -1, -1 };
    }
```

Here I've used `long` for dictionary key, `p` and `q` in order to cope with *integer overflow*

Comment: Does this take into account the complexity of the Linq statement?

Comment: @Strom: Linq's `GroupBy` uses *hash* and has as well as the entire query `O(n)` time complexity.

Comment: @canton7: the final pair can well apper at the *very end*: `nums = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7}, k = 9`. So, tehcnically, we can only subtract `1` from `Length`:  `for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length - 1; ++i) {...}`

Comment: As @Strom pointed out in another answer, expanding the Dictionary has log complexity, and the GroupBy likely has the same.

Comment: @canton7: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532678/what-is-the-complexity-of-these-dictionary-methods

Comment: @Dimitry that is what I'm referring to, yes

Comment: @canton7, if the size of the Dictionary is known at creation there is no expansion. thus no penalty.

Answer (score 0):

While everyone debates the fastest algorithm, the following code is quicker than O(n^2) it runs on average O(n log n) and in N space.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class Solution
{
    public int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target)
    {
        int[] output = new int[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int n = 1; n < nums.Length; n++)
            {
                if ((nums[i] + nums[n]) == target)
                {
                    output[0] = n;
                    output[1] = i;
                    return output; //early exit giving O(n log n) vs (n^2)
                }
            }
        }
        return output; // degenerate case no solution exists
    }
}
```

Comment: See the comments on the OP for some simple improvement to make

Comment: This answers the question asked by the OP. Quicker, not the quickest or best, but better.

Comment: Well, it repeats the code from the question at least

Comment: @canton7, Thanks I have included the change. Although one iteration of the internal loop doesn't improve the big O.

Comment: @canton7, no it is the expected answer from a first year CS student. The OP made that clear by asking for a sorting code example. I have updated with comment the change, in case you missed it.

Comment: @Strom this is pointless since it will give a compiler error 
" not all code paths return a value"

Comment: @VishalTyagi, Thanks, I moved it instead of copying it.